# Makefile error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3

Tags: c, makefile, sqlite

I've installed `sqlite3` from source on Linux and placed this into the subdirectory of C code with a Makefile. This is what the `Makefile` looks like

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -g -std=c99

SOURCES := src/file1.c src/file2.c src/file3.c
LIB     := -lm -lsqlite3 
INC     := -I include -I path/to/pathname/sqlite3/include 

all:
    @mkdir -p bin/

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES) main.c  -L path/to/pathname/sqlite3/ -o bin/software $(LIB) $(INC)

clean:
    rm -f bin/sofware
```

However, whenever I try executing `make`, I get this error:

```
gcc -Wall -g -std=c99 src/file1.c src/file2.c src/file3.c -I include -I path/to/pathname/sqlite3/include 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I don't understand. `sqlite3` is in `path/to/pathname/sqlite3/`

Here is the list of files/executables in `path/to/pathname/sqlite3/`:

```
aclocal.m4      config.log     configure.ac  install-sh     ltmain.sh    missing  shell.o       sqlite3.h   sqlite3.pc.in
autom4te.cache  config.status  depcomp       lib            Makefile     README   sqlite3       sqlite3.lo  tea
bin             config.sub     include       libsqlite3.la  Makefile.am  share    sqlite3.c     sqlite3.o
config.guess    configure      INSTALL       libtool        Makefile.in  shell.c  sqlite3ext.h  sqlite3.pc
```

How does one properly allow this C code to compile properly with access to sqlite3?

Comment: `LDFLAGS = -Lpath/to/pathname/sqlite3/lib` (assuming `lib` is where the library binary actually resides).

Comment: Also, something not quite right about the info you have provided. The makefile says `main.c` should be included in the build command line. But it is not shown in your output. Nor does the `gcc` line show `-lsqlite3`. Not sure whether something is wrong there or you have pasted in the wrong output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add -L/path/to/lib/dir